# Error en el cálculo de coordenadas 2D a partir de una matriz de distancias

Tags: python, numpy

Estoy intentando obtener coordenadas 2D entre 0 y 1 a partir de una matriz de distancia, siguiendo los métodos que se especifican en los siguientes posts (Multi-Dimensional Scaling):

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156161/finding-the-coordinates-of-points-from-distance-matrix

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61648004/how-to-implement-finding-the-coordinates-of-points-from-distance-matrix-in-pytho

Sin embargo, al intentar implementarlo me da un error y me cuesta encontrar el origen de este error. Esto es lo que estoy haciendo:

Esta es la matriz de distancias (como se puede ver, la distancia máxima es 1, para que todos los puntos estén entre 0 y 1):

```
import numpy as np
import math

distance_matrix = np.array(
    [
        [0.0, 0.47659458, 0.22173311, 0.46660708, 0.78423276],
        [0.47659458, 0.0, 0.69805139, 0.01200111, 0.6629441],
        [0.22173311, 0.69805139, 0.0, 0.68249177, 1.0],
        [0.46660708, 0.01200111, 0.68249177, 0.0, 0.6850815],
        [0.78423276, 0.6629441, 1.0, 0.6850815, 0.0],
    ]
)
```

Aquí hago el Multi-Dimensional Scaling en sí:

```
def x_coord_of_point(D, j):
    return ( D[0,j]**2 + D[0,1]**2 - D[1,j]**2 ) / ( 2*D[0,1] )

def coords_of_point(D, j):
    x = x_coord_of_point(D, j)
    return np.array([x, math.sqrt( D[0,j]**2 - x**2 )])
    
def calculate_positions(D):
    (m, n) = D.shape
    P = np.zeros( (n, 2) )
    tr = ( min(min(D[2,0:2]), min(D[2,3:n])) / 2)**2
    P[1,0] = D[0,1]
    P[2,:] = coords_of_point(D, 2)
    for j in range(3,n):
        P[j,:] = coords_of_point(D, j) 
        if abs( np.dot(P[j,:] - P[2,:], P[j,:] - P[2,:]) - D[2,j]**2 ) > tr:
            P[j,1] = - P[j,1]
    return P

P = calculate_positions(distance_matrix)
print(P)
```

```
Output: [[ 0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.47659458  0.        ]
 [-0.22132834  0.01339166]
 [ 0.46656063  0.0065838 ]
 [ 0.42244347 -0.66072879]]
```

Hago lo siguiente para que todos los puntos estén entre 0 y 1:

```
P = P-P.min(axis=0)
```

Una vez que tengo el conjunto de puntos que se supone que satisfacen la matriz de distancia, calculo la matriz de distancia de los puntos para ver si es igual a la original:

```
def compute_dist_matrix(P):
    dist_matrix = []
    for i in range(len(P)):
        lis_pos = []
        for j in range(len(P)):
            dist = np.linalg.norm(P[i]-P[j])
            lis_pos.append(dist)
        dist_matrix.append(lis_pos)
    return np.array(dist_matrix)

compute_dist_matrix(P)
```

```
Output: array([[0.        , 0.47659458, 0.22173311, 0.46660708, 0.78423276],
       [0.47659458, 0.        , 0.69805139, 0.01200111, 0.6629441 ],
       [0.22173311, 0.69805139, 0.        , 0.68792266, 0.93213762],
       [0.46660708, 0.01200111, 0.68792266, 0.        , 0.66876934],
       [0.78423276, 0.6629441 , 0.93213762, 0.66876934, 0.        ]])
```

Como se puede ver, si comparamos esta matriz con la matriz de distancia original al principio del post, no hay ningún error en los primeros términos de la matriz, pero a medida que nos acercamos al final, el error se hace cada vez más grande. Si la matriz de distancia es más grande (más puntos, no sólo 4) que la que utilizo en este ejemplo, los erros entonces se vuelven enormes.

No sé si el origen del error está en las funciones que calculan P o tal vez la función "compute_dist_matrix" sea el problema.

¿Alguien encuentra donde está el error? O tal vez, ¿hay una manera más fácil de calcular todo esto? Tal vez hay algunas funciones en alguna biblioteca que ya realizan esta transformación.

Comment: Lo mas probable es que sea el error de redondeo del computador, aparte de eso, te recomiendo usar `abs()` para obtener el valor absoluto del numero, es decir para que este entre `0` y `1`, reemplazando a esta linea ` P-P.min(axis=0)`

Comment: Gracias @Christian por lo de abs lo primero. Y en cuanto al redondeo del computador, hay alguna solución para que eso no ocurra?